# How to apply specific revision from Git of a configuration file and roll-back if not ok?

Tags: git, puppet, theforeman

Problem: I want to be able to install an RPM with a specific revision of a configuration file.

Take the following example:

Say I have an RPM I want to guarantee is installed and running. No problem here. 
Now say I want to provide a different configuration file for each puppet environment. Also no problem here.

But now say I want to do versioning control **specifically and only** on the configuration files, would then like to be able to detect that a new version exists of a configuration file, say in a Git repository and if so, the config file is applied and services restarted. If services run correctly then ok, if not, then old revision of configuration file should be re-applied (roll-back of configuration file to previous revision).

Is this at all possible with puppet? If so, what kind of architecture would be the best approach for such a scenario?

Any point in the right direction or help on this matter will be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a scheme after the following fashion:

1. Have Puppet deploy credentials for your central git repository on each agent
2. Use the [vcsrepo type](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-vcsrepo#to-clonepull-a-repository) to allow Puppet to maintain a clone of the repo on each agent with the desired revision
3. Have the config file resources use local sources.

   ```
   source => '/path/to/local/git/clone/my_config.ini'
   ```
4. Use the [validate_cmd](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#file-attribute-validate_cmd) parameter to make Puppet roll back if things are not OK.

   ```
   validate_cmd => 'apache2ctl configtest'
   ```
5. Have the file `notify` the respective service, or the service `subscribe` to make Puppet reload the configuration upon changing it.

I don't see why you keep referencing RPM packages - they are not pertinent to the issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Frank! True I don't need to mention the RPM, its just that for my particular use case we are using custom RPM file with Java applications that run in Tomcat. Each Java application then has quite a few properties files, which is what I am calling the config files. In any case thanks for you tips, very very helpfull, will now investigate and try this out.